# How to display only date when displaying the date in view?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have try different ways to only display the date on the column thisdate, and I have look at other answers online.

How can I only get the date to display for the item?

Model:

```
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")]
        public DateTime? thisdate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thisdate) </td> 
                        //displays date like : 11/30/2018 12:00:00 AM
                         <td>@item.thisdate.ToShortDateString();</td>
                         //this gives me a error 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShordDateString' accepting a first argument
                }
```

Comment: Since it's a nullable property you need to get its value `@item.thisdate.Value.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: @Dumisani i tried that and get a error '500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: That's probably because not all records have a date. Check my answer

Comment: Your `@Html.DisplayFor()` will work just fine (and it will render 2018/11/30) based on your `DataFormatString`, so if its not working, then you have shown the wrong code, or you already have defined a custom `DisplayTemplate` for `DateTime?` in your `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a nullable property you need to get its value and also check if the value is not null

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if(@item.thisdate.HasValue)
    {
        <td>@item.thisdate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
    }
}
```